# Qt Designer / PyQt - dynamically duplicate a tab widget with embedded widgets intact

Tags: python, qt, python-3.x, pyqt, qt-designer

I have C# experience, and I'm making my first Python app. I'm part way done the UI in QT Designer, and soon I'll try PyQt to integrate it with my code. This is a general guidance question for best approach.

I have a tab widget containing various things in each tab. I would like the entire tab widget to be duplicatable with a plus button. So basically, a scroll view containing as many of these tab widgets as the user wants. The user could duplicate an existing one as a new instance, or create a blank one.

Could someone please help me understand how to accomplish this? Does it work like this?

1. Create the scroll view.
2. Put the tab widget inside the scroll view.
3. Add duplicate and delete buttons in the corner of the tab widget.
4. Put a plus button just outside the scroll view.
5. Accomplish all of the rest via python code? Or would I be missing out on some Qt Designer tricks?

Any tips on how to do this in QT Designer and also coding in PyQt would be appreciated.

Additionally, perhaps off topic, but any general tips on PyQt installation and usage would be nice. v5 not v4? I'm running Python 3.6 32 bit, which I was told should run 3.5 packages fine (but 64 bit may not).

Thanks,

Comment: I would put the TabWidget in a separate `.ui` file. This enables you to easily create multiple instances of it.

Comment: Thanks @GeorgSchölly, that sounds perfect. I will try out some tests before reworking my ui files.

Answer (score 0):

First the out of topic : use PyQt5 if you start a new project. Qt 4 has reached end of life and won't see any new release unless it's a critical security fix.

As for most of your questions: if you want to use Designer then you should start by taking a look at [Qt Designer's documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtdesigner-manual.html). It will get you started nicely.

As for 5, it depends on tastes. Developers have been using both for various reasons. It's really up to you decide which style fits your needs best. There's no tricks in designer that you can't accomplish in code.

Comment: PyQt4 can be compiled against Qt 5. But you're right, there is no reason to use PyQt4 with Python 3.